# ITK: best way to apply a filter to part of an image

Tags: itk

I am an ITK newbie, so please excuse any misused jargon.  I have a series of JPEG files which show screenshots from ultrasound imaging software.  I'd like to find just the ultrasound part of the screen (specifically NOT a square), then run that part of the image through some filters, leaving the rest of the screen untouched.  I imagine I can use a binary mask filter to extract the area of interest, process the masked image, and then use a combination of mask and addition to get the two parts back together.  Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I believe using a binary mask is a reasonable approach. I have done similar with ITK/VTK.

Comment: @user2715819: I think that your approach is right, I would operate the same way. BTW, I link the [RegionOfInterestImageFilter](http://www.itk.org/Doxygen/html/classitk_1_1RegionOfInterestImageFilter.html) class: it permits to apply a filter to a specific region of the image, and maybe it'd be useful to you. If the region can be a complex polygon as you say, however, things could be more difficult (filters usually operate on matrices...)

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  In my case, I have found that I can also use an imageAdaptor (because I am interested in all of the non-black and non-color pixels in a region of the image).  Your point about filters working on matrices is a good one, and I'll probably stick with a square (masked) ROI and see how the edge effects play out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may create a binary mask by hand of your region of interest. A very simple tool for this is ITK-Snap.

If you are not interested in certain pixels of a certain intensity / color, you may use a pipeline of BinaryThreshold filters

Comment: Thanks.  I ended up taking the second route, running the image through a series of BinaryThreshold filters.  I then saved a mask image which may be applied to similar files with logical filters.  I did not try using ITK-Snap for hand-generation, though.  That is good to know about.

Answer (score 1):

These itkUltrasoundProbeGeometryCalculator classes where written to find the sector portions of an ultrasound image screenshot for extraction and further analysis:

https://github.com/KitwareMedical/TubeTK/blob/master/Base/USTK/itkUltrasoundProbeGeometryCalculator.h

Comment: Thanks, Matt.  I am no longer actively working on this project, but if/when I pick it up again I will look into using this more robust method of extraction.